# react native - make specific component not RTL in RTL device

Tags: react-native, slider, right-to-left

I'm using https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider, to create a range slider.
every thing work great, when I'm in LTR, but when i switch to RTL the maximum and minimum position flip over, when I need them to stay the same. because numbers in Hebrew are still LTR and not RTL. Anybody here knows how to make one component to ignore RTL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your plugin does not support the RTL version, I've changed part of the code in the same plugin. for example, I've changed right to left. you have to change part of the code in this plugin